# Duplicate key error in mongoose in nested design schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a website in NodeJS and MongoDB using mongoose and I have a model **Photo** and another model **Photographer** as below:

```
var photographerSchema = new Schema({
    photographerId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    emailAddress: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: { type: String, default: '' },
    lastName: { type: String, default: '' },
    phoneNumber: { type: String, default: '' },
    address: { type: String, default: '' },
    profilePhoto: { type: String, default: 'media/UserPhotos' },
    photos: { type: [photoSchema], default: [] }
});

var photoSchema = new Schema({
    photoId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, default: '' },
    path: { type: String, default: 'media/images' },
    photographer: { type: photographerSchema, default: null },
    isAppoved: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

now there's a problem! when I want to add multiple photos by a photographer account, gives me the error **E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.photodatas index: photographer.emailAddress_1 dup key: { : "photographeremail@email.com" }**

any help makes me appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to add those photos?

Comment: @robertklep of course.Here you are:
        Photographer.find({ emailAddress: request.session.user_id }, function      (error, data) {
            if (data) {
                form.on('file', function (field, file) {
                    if (file.size != 0) {  //some process on files;
                        var user = data[0];
                        //variables are defined here;
                        var item = {title: fName, path: filePath,photographer: user};
                        var nPhoto = new Photo(item);  
                    } //handling errors;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are adding for each photo same object, but Mongoose is trying to create new Photographer document. In photoSchema you should use ref for photographer.

```
var photoSchema = new Schema({
    photoId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, default: '' },
    path: { type: String, default: 'media/images' },
    photographer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Photographer' },
    isAppoved: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

And then when you are saving new Photo, just use `photographer.photographerId` in photographer property.

```
var photo = new Photo({
    somedata: "data",
    ...
    photographer: photographer.photographerId
});
```

Then when you want to get all photos you can populate photographer like this:

```
Photo
.find()
.populate('photographer')
.exec(function (err, photos) {
  // yey!
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but in first code part, did you mean:
photographer: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Photographer'} instead of isApproved: ......?

Comment: I assumed that your schema name is Photographer, but remember to set it like you've named your schema.